# Recuperando item em outra função com jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como consigo guardar um item via jquery para ser utilizado depois?

tenho a seguinte estrutura, onde recupera o item de um evento onclick de um button, recupero a linha da tabela  a que esse button está associada e exibo a informação referente a essa linha com uma `modal`

```
RemoveTableRow = function(item) {   

     var Linha = $(item).closest('tr');

     var Codigo   = $(Linha).find('td[data-codigo]').data('codigo');

     AbreModal('Deseja realmente excluir esse Contato?');

    return false;         
}
```

então quando o usuário clica-se no button excluir pertencente a modal, para remover a linha da tabela gostaria de recuperar esse `item` para poder executar a função de fato para excluir:

```
var tr = $(item).closest('tr'); 

tr.fadeOut(400, function() {              
    tr.remove();            
});
```

Comment: Em vez de remover, você pode apenas ocultar... e se precisar dos dados novamente, ele ainda estará na página, apesar de oculto.

Comment: mas eu não consigo pegar porque estou enviando o item no evento onclick do botão excluir que tem em cada linha da tabela ... e eu preciso pegar ele no botão de confirmação que é um evento do botão modal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você está capturando o referido código na função `RemoveTableRow` em:

```
var Codigo   = $(Linha).find('td[data-codigo]').data('codigo');
```

Você pode enviar esse código na função `AbreModal` como um segundo parâmetro:

```
AbreModal('Deseja realmente excluir esse Contato?', Codigo);
```

E incluir no botão da modal o código passado na função. Algo como:

```
function AbreModal(mensagem, codigo){
   // exibe a modal com os parâmetros "mensagem" e "codigo"
}
```

Comment: desculpe se não soube explicar direito, mas eu não quero passar o código via parametro e sim o elemento Linha via parametro e eu não quero passar ele para a função abremodal mas sim quando eu clicar em um button que está dentro do modal ...

Comment: esse item 'linha' só vai ser utilizado caso o usuario clicar em sim pois na janela modal vai aparecer sim ou não ... por isso o evento do click button vai ser em outra função ... e por isso eu disse 'Como consigo guardar um item via jquery para ser utilizado depois?' quando eu falo depois é com relação a executar a função click do botão sim do modal

Comment: @BrunoAparecidodaSilva Você pode usar a variável `Codigo` criada na função `RemoveTableRow`, mas tem que tirar o `var` dela para que essa variável possa ser capturada em outra função. Entendeu?

Comment: Eu entendi amigo, eu sei como funciona passagem de parametro, mas acho que você ainda não entendeu kkkkk

Comment: @BrunoAparecidodaSilva rsrs... vc quer que o botão "SIM" da modal pegue o código da linha, não é?

Comment: Não, quero que o botão sim da modal pegue a var linha que no caso é o <tr> que eu consegui recuperar por causa do button da tabela

Comment: @BrunoAparecidodaSilva pois então? não basta pergar o que já foi colocado no `var Linha = $(item).closest('tr');`? Agora, teria que tirar o `var` pra variável `Linha`ter escopo global.

Comment: Desculpe a minha ignorancia, não sabia que eu podia utilizar isso como váriavel global. eu chamo dois métodos que não tem relação nenhum em momentos diferentes e precisava da informação do outro ... mas como consigo definir variavel global é possivel fazer isso, muito obrigado

Comment: @BrunoAparecidodaSilva Pode, basta tirar o `var`